# How to find document element by regexp?

Tags: javascript

for example I have many input elements with name "test_(1...100)". I want to find all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just so happened to have had the exact same problem, this is how I solved it:

```
var divs=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var re  = /test_[\d]+/i;
for (thediv in divs) {
    if (divs[thediv].id != null && divs[thediv].id.match(re)) {
        //your stuff here
    }
}
```

And as slhck pointed out, to make the chance of getting an answer bigger you should start accepting some answers to your questions. This is done by using the Green checkmark next to every answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RegularExpressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html). An [online tool](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) might help.

The expression you need will be something like:

```
test_[\d]+
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the global/'greedy' (/g)  option to get ALL your matches not just the first one.  And if case-sensitivity isn't required use the flag to indicate this too (/i)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, then you can use .filter() with a function:

```
$('input').filter(function(){
   return this.name.match(/^test/);
}).css({background: 'red'});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nLLUD/).

If you are not using any library that would help you with that then you have to iterate over every input element that you find and match its name with your regex on every iteration.